# Multi-layered path styles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, style

Is it possible to style a vector layer in Leaflet with multiple "style layers"? For example, could a polygon layer be styled with multiple borders, of different weights/colours/opacity? OpenLayers supports this, and it would be very useful for more complex cartographic styling.

Answer (score 1):

After asking the Leaflet devs if this was possible, @Liedman wrote this plugin to achieve exactly what was required:

https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-multi-style

Thanks, Per!